# Applying Poisson distribution to binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The problem is from Introduction to probability 2nd edition byDimitri P. Bertseka> It goes like this:

> You go to a party with 500 guests. What is the probability that exactly one other guest has the same birthday as you? Calculate this exactly and also approximately by using Poisson PMF. (For simplicity, exclue birthdays on Feburary 29.)

And in the solution, professor uses  $\lambda = np = \frac{499}{365} $ for $P(x=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}$.
Isn't $\lambda$ supposed to be $\frac{500}{365}$ because there are basically $500$ trials in this case and each probability is $1\over365$ ?

Comment: It depends whether it is $500$ guests in total (counting with you) or $501$ (that is $500 + $ you ). I assume the first case, hence there are $499$ other guests.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I've mistaken such a simple thing. Thanks again for your comment bro. I've been wondering for over an hour what I did wrong! :)

Comment: Sometimes the solutions are the easiest one ^^, goodluck